# using @ error controller within heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

How do I use the `@` error controller within heredoc? Like in a case where i want to redisplay the contents of an input  form field that has not yet passed validation: I get error when I use `@` within heredoc as follows:

```
 <<<EOS
     <input name="firstname" type="text" value="{@$_POST['firstname']}" />
 EOS;

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

Comment: Why do you need the `@` anyway? That only shows a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this within your heredoc, but before is fine:

```
$value = @<<<HDOC
    Name: {$_POST['firstname']}
HDOC;
```

The same works with double-quotes (the example you showed is NOT heredoc):

```
$value = @"Name: {$_POST['firstname']}";
```